# How to remove from a 3d numpy array (rows of 28X28) all rows that exists in other 3d numpy array ( Python )?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have two 3d numpy arrays that includes rows of 28x28 images. One ("A") with a shape of (1000, 28, 28) and the other ("B") is with a shape of (100, 28, 28) that some are include within the latter. How can I filter "A" removing all elements that are also included in B?

Comment: If you remove elements from `A` it can no longer maintain its original shape, is that what you want? Or, by removing, you do mean replace with a specific value (e.g. `0.0` or `NaN`)?

Answer (score 0):

List generator:

```
new_A = [line for line in A if line not in B]
```

emm, is it helpful? It should be faster than iteration.

Comment: What do you mean faster than iteration? It *is* iteration

Comment: Generator expression differs from Iteration.Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

index the first array with a comprehension:

```
filtered = A[[0 if i in B else 1 for i in A]]
```